# R package not available in batch mode

Tags: r, package

I have been running a bash script (under Ubuntu) that calls and runs some R scripts to plot some maps with ggplot2. As it is a production system I don't update any new R or package releases. But recently I tried to install plotly with an error message output.

Now, when trying to run the script (calling a php webpage trhough a browser; that was running fine for a lot of time) an error with crayon package halts and exits the script without plotting the maps.

```
    '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file=./RAMS-mapa-onades-zones-manual.R'
    Loading required package: sp
    Loading required package: methods
    Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
      call: loadNamespace(name)
      error: there is no package called 'crayon'
    Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'
    Execution halted
```

But if I run from a terminal or with RStudio server `crayon` package is loaded, `ggplot2` is also properly loaded, and the maps are produced.

`crayon` package (located at */home/meteo/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1*) called as

```
library("crayon", lib.loc= c("/home/meteo/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1", "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library", "/usr/lib/R/library"))
```

R session info on Rstudio Server:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] crayon_1.3.4    rgdal_0.9-1     rgeos_0.3-8     raster_2.3-24   gpclib_1.5-5    mapproj_1.2-2   maps_2.3-9     
 [8] stringr_0.6.2   plyr_1.8.1      ggplot2_3.2.0   maptools_0.8-34 sp_1.2-3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.2-4 lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.4.0        
 [8] rlang_0.3.4      dplyr_0.8.1      tools_3.2.2      gtable_0.1.2     withr_2.1.2      digest_0.6.8     lazyeval_0.2.2  
[15] assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3     purrr_0.3.2      glue_1.3.1       labeling_0.3     pillar_1.4.1     scales_1.0.0    
[22] foreign_0.8-66   pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Maybe there is a version conflict? How do I check?

Comment: if i understand correctly the error occurs when you run `/RAMS-mapa-onades-zones-manual.R`. Does that script include loading the crayon package like this `library("crayon", lib.loc= c("/home/meteo/....`? Could you give the output of `print(.libPahts())` when called from / added to `/RAMS-mapa-onades-zones-manual.R`?

Comment: Hi @BigDataScientist. `print(.libPaths())` gives an error message > print(.libPahts())
`Error in print(.libPahts()) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error: could not find function ".libPahts"`

Comment: If I run the script from RStudio server it works fine, without calling crayon. If I run (inside a browser window) a php script calling a bash script that has a R CMD BATCH script.R then it crashes with this message about crayon. I added the explicit call to crayon to try solving the problem but it has not worked.

Comment: sry typo, its `.libPaths()`,...

Comment: [1] "/home/meteo/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"              
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                     "/usr/lib/R/library"

Comment: Your session info indicates you're using R 3.2.2, yet your library path points to R 3.1? You should probably use `library` without indicating paths explicitly and install any missing packages for the R version you're actually using.

Comment: You might find it helpful to use MRAN and `checkpoint` in order to grab package versions from the specific date matching when your app went into production. While this may not fix your immediate problem, it might minimize having to re-test and confirm all new packages (if, indeed, an older version is otherwise not available elsewhere).

Comment: Hi Alexis. I have updated R to 3.2.5 but adding `.libPaths(c("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/library"))` to avoid pointing to R 3.1. Now the scripts works if run from RStudio Server but error still persists, now when calling `lattice` and `sp`

Answer (score 0):

what version of R is in `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`? Basically it appears you are in a slight "dependency hell" I would run `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` and check to see if crayon is installed there. @Alexis is correct though, it is not wise to mix versions like that. Let R handle library location unless you are trying to separate packages. Check the libraries for 3.2.2 and see if crayon is installed. you may have switched your R version since plotly depends on R >=3.2.0 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/

I think the easy fix would be to correct your .libpaths() i.e not call the 3.1 library and install the correct version of the packages you need.

OR

switch from R 3.2 back to R 3.1

Comment: Just updated to R 3.2.5. From command line packages are loaded. From RStudio Server the script runs fine calling with `library()` but when running in batch mode now it is `lattice` that gives the error message. Tried adding `.libPaths(c("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/site-library","/usr/lib/R/library"))` to script but the error persists. Maybe a user permission issue?

Comment: Probably not permissions. You just dont have the libraries installed in both the Rstudio usr library and the console library. keep in mind that Rstudio uses a separate library. use sys.getEnv() to see the difference.